# I want to redirect the current page after submitting the form....it should return the page from where request is send using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I want to redirect the current page after submitting the form as same form is in Multiple pages *(about 25 pages)* so it should return the page from where form is submit using php

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="submitEnquery.php">
  <input name="name" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" >
  <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Type your message here....">/textarea>                          
  <button name="submit" type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['msg'];
    $to = 'qwert01@exmple.com' . ', ';
    $to.= 'qwert003@exmple.com';
    $subject = "Enquery Form";
    $message = "
          <html>
          <head>
              <title>HTML email</title>
              <style>
              body{ background: #E6E4DE; }
              img{ width:200px; height:55px; display:block; text-align:center; 
              margin:0 auto; }
              h3{ text-align:center;margin:25px auto; }
              table { font-family: arial, sans-serif; border: 1px solid #ddd; 
              border-collapse: collapse; width: 70%; margin: 0 auto; }
              td, th { border: 1px solid #ddd; text-align: left; padding: 10px 
              15px; vertical-align: top; }
              </style>
          </head>
          <body>               
              <h3>Senders Detail down below</h3>
              <table rules='all' cellpadding='10'>
                  <tr style='background: #eee;'>
                      <th style='width:25%'>Name</th>
                      <th style='width:75%'>" . $name . "</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td style='width:25%'>Email</td>
                      <td style='width:75%'>" . $email . "</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td style='width:25%'>Message</td>
                      <td style='width:75%'>" . $msg . "</td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </body>
          </html>
      ";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers.= 'From: ' . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Cc: qwert65494@exmple.com' . "\r\n";
    $headers.= 'Bcc: iqwert@exmple.com' . "\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    header('Refresh:0;');
  }

  echo '<h3>Sent Sccessfully...!</h3>';
?>
```

The code is working properly.
It sends mail no problem but the issue is how can redirect to the page from where en-query(contact) form is submitted.

Comment: Change your `header()` to reflect where you want to go.

Comment: a safe way would be to set a php session variable at the beginning of each page containing the form, with the file name it comes from, and retreive it in submitEnquery.php. I personnally wouldn't trust server vars that can be absent, or form data that can be modified

Comment: okay @Kaddath i will try this in future.. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

OR

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```